# Install android sdk 2.2 on htc g1 device

Tags: android

On my android htc g1 device currently there is 1.6 sdk is install. But now i am working in android 2.2, so now i want install this new sdk in my HTC g1 device and i am working on Linux machine. I don't know how to do this. Help me...

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These links may help although these are for G2

http://things-that-i-noticed.blogspot.com/2010/07/google-ion-android-21-cyanogenmod.html
http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/278-installation-support-line-cyanogenmod-5-for-dreammagic/

Comment: thanks Gopi. But i am working on the Linux machine not on mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official way to do this per [a Google IO fireside chat](http://gizmodo.com/5544136/android-22-will-never-come-to-the-g1)

Unofficially, the device can be updated through CyanogenMod, as per Gopi.  Again, this isn't an official update and bugs may be present.